# XHRHttpRequest to Dropbox XHR failed loading: OPTIONS

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, dropbox-api

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate of another question but i have looked and not found one so here goes.  If this is a duplicate, then please post a link to the original so I may take a look.

When I attempt to use XMLHttpRequest to transfer a file to my dropbox I get a XHR failed loading OPTIONS error.  I am not using ajax which is why I believe this is not a duplicate of previously asked questions.

I copied the code here for my code: https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/03/how-formio-uses-dropbox-as-a-file-backend-for-javascript-apps/

but here's my code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var passedData = new Array("one", "two", "three")
var filename = "test";
var file = new File(passedData, filename);
xhr.open('POST', 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 'AccessToken');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Dropbox-API-Arg', JSON.stringify({
    path: '/' +  file.name,
    mode: 'overwrite',
    autorename: false,
    mute: false,
}));
xhr.send(file);
```

Full Error:
VM639 framework.js:82 XHR failed loading: OPTIONS "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload".
upload  @   VM639 framework.js:82
onclick @   View.html:675

I just realized I forgot to mention that this was working just fine until march 25th.  Might be irrelevant but I wouldn't know.

The above works fine, but the problem is when I paste it into my main script.
I'm calling it the same exact way, with a button, and sending the same file, but i get that message.

Comment: note that "AJAX" stands for "asynchronous JavaScript and XML", so using `XMLHttpRequest` is technically making an Ajax request. Can you add the full error so that we know why the XHR fails?

Comment: Oh sorry about that
VM639 framework.js:82 XHR failed loading: OPTIONS "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload".
upload @ VM639 framework.js:82
onclick @ View.html:675

Comment: Mmh this isn't helping much, can you add this error hadling `xhr.onload = function() { if (xhr.status !== 200) { var errorMessage = xhr.response || 'Unable to upload file'; console.error('Failed with status (' + xhr.status + ') - error: ' + errorMessage ); } };` (before `xhr.open`). And see what it outputs in console?

Comment: Thx for telling me about console.error() though,  if it wasn't for you I probably never would've know about it.  It's certainly something I'll be using a lot.

Comment: if it doesn't print anything, you can also try `xhr.onerror = function(event) { console.error('Error with status (' + event.target.status + ')'); }`, or look at the network tab in the developper console for meaningful infos about the error.

Comment: The network tab shows 0/however large the file I'm trying to send.

Comment: Still the same, xhr.onerror also doesn't print.

Comment: The message I get in my console shows up in info so I believe it may not be an error

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Dropbox-API-upload/m-p/336795#M19608 ]

Comment: So, is it still off topic?  It can be reproduced using the same code I posted.  Or rather, how can I change my question to reflect that I was using local host?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that I was doing this at local host.  Once I stuck it on a server, it worked.

Comment: Oh thx Greg, totally forgot about that

Comment: I redacted it from your post, but you should revoke that access token that you shared. You can use the API v2 Explorer to do so if you'd like: https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/#auth_token/revoke